# What is the 'right' definition of zero measure subsets of Banach spaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

**Question.** There are several ways of defining a notion of a 'zero measure' subset of a Banach space $X$. Which one is the 'right' or failing that, the preferred notion? [See below for a more precise reformulation of the question.]

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space. The obvious problem when trying to extend the notion of negligible (or 'zero measure') subsets from the finite-dimensional setting is that often $X$ will not admit a natural measure. (In contrast $\mathbf{R}^n$ has the Lebesgue measure.)

There are several approaches that circumnavigate this issue, for example:

- *Haar null sets* are those subsets $A \subset X$ for which there is a Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $X$ so that every translate of $A$ has $\mu$-measure zero: $\mu(A - x) = 0$ for all $x \in X$, which apparently go back to Christensen [1].
- There are *$\Gamma$-null sets* as defined by Lindenstrauss and Preiss, *Gaussian null sets*, *Aronszajn null sets* and more. A discussion of the various notions is given in a paper of Bogachev [2].

I am interested in results for function spaces—say $X = C^{k,\alpha}$ is a Holder space for example—and where one tries to prove that some property holds for 'almost every' map.

**Question'.** Is one of these notions preferred over the others in this context? Is there a rule of thumb when to use which one?

[1] J.P.R. Christensen. On sets of Haar measure zero in abelian Polish groups, *Israel J. Math.* **13** (1972), 255-260.
[2] V.I. Bogachev. Negligible sets in infinite-dimensional Banach spaces. *Analysis Math.*, **44** (3) (2018), 299–323.

Comment: Doesn't this somewhat depend on the problem one is studying.  For instance, Morgan showed uniquness for area minimizers for generic boundaries where generic meant away from a set of measure zero (using some analog of Brownian motion).  White later showed this uniqueness away from a set of codimension 1.  White's result is stronger and his condition is arguably less technical, but Morgan's result is arguably more natural.

Comment: @RBega2 I wouldn't be surprised if it did. I was hoping for an answer that could state something like 'If the problem has this-or-that property, then null sets in the ...-sense are most natural'. By the way, do you have a reference for White's result?

Comment: It is section 7 of "The space of m-dimensional surfaces that are stationary for a parametric elliptic functional".

Comment: @RBega2 Thank you, I appreciate the reference! Can I ask you a quick follow-up? White mentions that the result works 'only with regular immersed surfaces'. Is this a problem in the high dimension, codimension one case, where there can be a small singular set? Mind you, this is admittedly a bit orthogonal to the question I'm asking here.

Comment: The argument White uses is a PDE one and I doesn't directly work in the singular setting.  I think there has been some quite recent work which has started to suggest how one might adapt things in the singular setting (at least when in the simplest situations e.g. when one has isolated singularities) but I'm not sure how far people have gotten and what does exist is quite technical.

Comment: @RBega2 That's interesting, I'm glad I asked you! I hadn't heard about this, but I'll see if I can find it on the arXiv.

Comment: It might not be immediately obvious, so the papers I was thinking of are this one by Edelen https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.13563 and some of the papers it references (e.g. this one https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.00548 by Z. Wang).  I've only skimmed these papers, so might be mistaken in exactly how relevant they are to your question.

Comment: @RBega2 Thanks, I'm not sure I would have found them. I appreciate the follow-up!

Answer (score 1):

The notion of Haar null sets is the most natural; indeed it was rediscovered in
[1], see also [2] and the references therein. The fact that Brownian motion plus a fixed continuous function is nowhere differentiable almost surely, implies that the set of functions in $C[0,1]$ that have at least one point of differentiability is Haar-null; this is simple enough to be included in a textbook, see Exercise 1.12 (pages 31 and 363)  in [3].

[1] http://yorke.umd.edu/Yorke_papers_most_cited_and_post2000/1992_12_Hunt_Sauer_Bull-AMS_Prevalence.pdf

[2] https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9304213.pdf

[3] https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/brownian-motion/F639B9A8403BD465F896F3E18A9C3382   https://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/book.pdf